# import cudf fail: Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: nvidia, cudf

cuda driver installed. cudf installed with conda. I try to import cudf but turns Illegal instruction (core dumped). I also tried uninstall cudf 0.7.2 and install cudf 0.6.1 . no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I also raised issue https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/1988 but did not get help. The current release may have problem.

I installed cuda 10 on linux 16.04 LTS . Then conda installed pytorch, pip install cupy, pyarrow and at last pip install cudf-cuda100 . These packages all work.

So I look forward coming release of cudf. My advice is avoid cudf 0.7 release.

Thank you.